# Show that $\alpha(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)\leq 1/4$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space, and let $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$ be sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal F$. I'm asked to show that the $\alpha$-mixing coefficient

$$\alpha(\mathcal A,\mathcal B):=\sup\bigg\{\big|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\big|:A\in\mathcal A, B \in \mathcal B\bigg\}$$

between $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ is bounded above by $1/4$.

My attempt:

Let $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$. Suppose first that $P(A)\geq P(B)$. Then

$$P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\leq P(B)-P(B)^2=P(B)P(B^c)$$

and

$$P(A)P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A\setminus B)P(B)+P(A\cap B)P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$\leq P(B^c)P(B)+P(A\cap B)(P(B)-1)\leq P(B)P(B^c)$$

Therefore $$|P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)|\leq  P(B)P(B^c)\leq 1/4$$

where the last inequality is because the function $x\mapsto x-x^2$ has a unique maximum at $x=1/2$. The case $P(A)\leq P(B)$ can be proven similarly. As $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$ were arbitrary we conclude that $\alpha(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)\leq 1/4$.

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't spot any flaws in this reasoning. Well done!

(Making this a community wiki since the answer doesn't contribute anything novel.)